# Rails_Admin related dropdowns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

Is there a way to filter a dropdown list based on another dropdown's value ? 
For example, if we have: `Class` and `Student` Models where `Student` have `class_id`; is there a way to filter the Students shown in the dropdown based on the selected `Class` ?

> EDIT

Apparently, rails_admin gem has an `association` relationship which I was looking for; but it doesn't work perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the related link: https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Associations-scoping which edited the origin question

Answer (score 1):

If you can use Javascript, this [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/88-dynamic-select-menus) will help you:

In this instance, your dropdowns may look like this:

```
<%= f.collection_select :class_id, Class.all, :id, :name, {:prompt => "Select a Class"}, {:id => "class"} %>

<%= f.collection_select :student_id, Student.all, :id, :name, {:prompt => "Select a Student"}, {:id => "student"} %>
```

And you would use Javascript to change the options in the Student dropdown. You can get the value of the class using:

```
class_id = $("#class").find(":selected").text()
```

Comment: I up-voted your answer based on its content, but this is not what I'm searching for.. I'm using Rails_Admin gem which auto-generates your backend..

Comment: Can you at least change the frontend and javascript? Could you use something like select2 js plugin?

Comment: @mlabarca unfortunately no

Answer (score 1):

Given two `<select>` elements `"Class"` and `"Student"`, with the `Student` list containing `data-class_id` attributes  referencing values from the `Class` list (see snippet below), you can filter the `"Student"` dropdown based on the `"Class"` dropdown's value using the following vanilla-JavaScript code:

```js
var firstSelectId = "Class";
var secondSelectId = "Student";
var data_attr = "class_id";
this.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  var firstSelect = document.getElementById(firstSelectId);
  var secondSelect = document.getElementById(secondSelectId);
  firstSelect.addEventListener("change", function(event) {
    var value = event.target.value;
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(secondSelect.options, function(item) {
      item.style.display = (item.dataset[data_attr] === value) ? 'inline' : 'none';
    });
    var selected = secondSelect.selectedOptions[0];
    if (selected && selected.dataset[data_attr] !== event.target.value) {
      secondSelect.selectedIndex = -1;
    }
  });
  firstSelect.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
});
```

```html
<form id="myform">
  Select a class and student:
  <select id="Class">
    <option value="1">Class1</option>
    <option value="2">Class2</option>
    <option value="3">Class3</option>
  </select>
  <select id="Student">
    <option value="StudentA" data-class_id="1">A</option>
    <option value="StudentB" data-class_id="2">B</option>
    <option value="StudentC" data-class_id="3">C</option>
    <option value="StudentD" data-class_id="2">D</option>
    <option value="StudentE" data-class_id="1">E</option>
    <option value="StudentF" data-class_id="1">F</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: I upvoted for the right logic, but this isn't what I'm looking for

Comment: @RocKhalil in that case, could you be more specific as to what you're looking for, and update your question to include the additional details?

Comment: you need to check rails_admin gem to know more about my question; anyway i've edited the question; I found how they use associations; but i'm keeping the answers here cause they're useful for anyone searching for related dropdows question..

Comment: @RocKhalil So to be clear, your question is more specifically, "Is there a way to filter a dropdown list based on another dropdown's value _using the `rails_admin` gem directly_?" Also, I see you added "Apparently, rails_admin gem has an `association` relationship which I was looking for; but it doesn't work perfectly." Does this mean your question is solved (in which case, post your own answer and mark it as accepted)? Or is there something specific about the `association` relationship not working perfectly that you still like an answer to?

Comment: Well, the `association` in `rails_admin` doesn't auto-refresh; so I think I'll be posting the related URL and close the question to keep the other answers;